# Algorithm to loop over an array from the middle outwards?

Tags: java, c++, c, algorithm

I'm working on a divide-and-conquer algorithm (in fact, one that does curve fitting to a number of input points). For the 'divide' part, I need to calculate an error term for each point, and if the error exceeds a given threshold, I wish to split the curve at that point and process the left and right sections of the input separately. A simple loop does the trick; but it would be advantageous for me to start at the middle of the current section and work outwards. (To clarify: if I do find a point whose error is too large, I recursively call and generate separate curves for the left and right sections - if all the points are within the threshold, then my curve fits and I return).

After a bit of head-scratching, I came up with this (the points are in an array, and the current section is from `startIndex` to `endIndex` inclusive):

```
int steps = (endIndex+1-startIndex);
int i = (startIndex+endIndex)>>1;
int stepdir = 1;
for(int q=0; q<steps; q++, i+=stepdir*q, stepdir=-stepdir)
{
   // test point i here and return early if error exceeds threshold
}
```

In other words, beginning near the middle, go one index forward, two back, three forward, four back... It works, and I'm sure it's efficient, but it strikes me that there should be a cleaner way to do it, in particular, I ended up having to check the Java language spec to make sure that the statements in the for update expression did evaluate in sequence (even though , is not a sequence operator as it is in C/C++).

Any ideas gratefully appreciated. Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: Are you using this loop as part of a recursive function?  i.e. split and call recursively on each split.

Comment: Yes... have edited the question to clarify. The end result is a series of 'simple' curves joined at some source points and 'close enough' to those in between.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This would be more readable imho

```
for (int q=0; q < steps; q++) {
   int index = i + ( q% 2 == 0 ? q/2 : -(q/2+1)); //index lookup here
}
```

Comment: Agreed. This makes it more apparent that each index is visited exactly once and the whole array is covered. Thanks.

Comment: doesn't that visit zero twice?

Comment: If q == 1 it would be index = i + -(0+1). 
If q == 2 it would be index = i + (1). I will add brackets to the example to make it more clear

Answer (score 1):

If your excess-error checker is simple (e.g. a function call), the clearest thing is to write :

```
int mid = npoints / 2;
for (int i = 0; i <= mid; i++) {
     if( excess_error(mid + i + 1) ) {
          // divide at mid + i + 1
     } else if excess_error(mid - i) {
          // divide at mid - i
     }
}
```

Again the "divide at xyz" code should be a function call, or you get cut & pasted code.

(I haven't thought carefully about corner cases, and off-by-one errors, so be careful when i==mid, but you get the picture.)

Comment: As soon as I find an error that's too big, I bust out of the loop and recurse the two halves... so the 'divide' part is pretty much set a divide point variable and break out of the loop. I do store the results of the error calculation for later reporting; so it's definitely worth pointing out that common behavior should be implemented within the function call.

Comment: Ok, so save-point and break is also pretty simple, the amount of code repetition would be almost as minimal as for a function call.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more general solution for anyone that needs to search outwards from an arbitrary point (in this example cell `[6]` in an array of length 7).

```
int arraySize = 7;
int start = 6;

for (int i=0; i < arraySize; i++) {
   int index = (start+((i%2==0)?i/2:arraySize-(i+1)/2))%arraySize;
   print(index+",");
}
exit();
```

Prints 6,5,0,4,1,3,2,