# Binary Search avoid unreadable entry (hole in list)

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search

I have implemented a binary search function but I have an issue with a list entry that may become unreadable. It's implemented in C++ but ill just use some pseudo code to make it easier. Please to not focus on the unreadable or string implementation, it's just pseudo code. What matter is that there are unreadable entries in the list that have to be navigated around.

```
int i = 0;
int imin = 0;
int imax = 99;
string search = "test";

while(imin <= imax)
{
    i = imin + (imax - imin) / 2;
    string text = vector.at(i);
    if(text.isUnreadable())
    {
        continue;
    }
    if(compare(text, search) = 0)
    {
         break;
    }
    else if(compare(text, search) < 0)
    {
         imin = i + 1;
    }
    else if(compare(text, search) > 0)
    {
         imax = i - 1;
    }
}
```

The searching itself is working pretty well, but the problem I have is how to avoid getting an endless loop if the text is unreadable. Anyone has a time tested approach for this? The loop should not just exit when unreadable but rather navigate around the hole.

Comment: What do you mean by *text is unreadable*?  Can you post an [mcve] that demonstrates the issue you are having?

Comment: What context does this code appear in? A function? Also when asking a technical question here, please post the **actual code**.

Comment: Why would be the text 'unreadable'?

Comment: Why do you have a `isUnreadable` function to being with?  What's wrong with just using `compare`, regardless of what the text consists of?  And even if you did need the `unreadable`, why would you want to keep it around inside the vector?  Just remove the unreadable entries from the vector before calling your search routine.

Comment: As I said it's just pseudo code, the actual code is too complex to post in its entirety. My question focuses rather on the strategy instead of the actual implementation.

Comment: Just to add context, the unreadable is based on a proprietary text container implementation for a specific application. I used string in my pseudo code to reduce example complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar task in one of projects - lookup on sequence where some of items are non-comparable.

I am not sure is this the best possible implementation, in my case it looks like this:

```
 int low = first_comparable(0,env);
 int high = last_comparable(env.total() - 1,env);
 while (low < high)
 {
     int mid = low + ((high - low) / 2);

     int tmid = last_comparable(mid,env);
     if( tmid < low ) 
     {
       tmid = first_comparable(mid,env);
       if( tmid == high )
         return high;
       if( tmid > high )
         return -1;
     }
     mid = tmid;
 ...
}
```

If `vector.at(mid)` item is non-comparable it does lookup in its neighborhood to find closest comparable.

first/last_comparable() functions return index of first comparable element from given index. Difference is in direction.

```
  inline int first_comparable( int n, E& env)
  {
    int n_elements = env.total();
    for( ; n < n_elements; ++n )
      if( env.is_comparable(n) )
        return n;
    return n;
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, I was actually thinking of a similar strategy over night. A linear search around the mid index would be to way to go. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I'm even thinking of a bidirectional search, instead of a unidirectional. Maybe you can consider it when you need it. Like `n % 2 = 0`

Comment: I was thinking of something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837990/algorithm-to-loop-over-an-array-from-the-middle-outwards.

Answer (score 0):

> the problem I have is how to avoid getting an endless loop if the text is unreadable.

Seems like that `continue` should be `break` instead, so that you break out of the loop. You'd probably want to set a flag or something to indicate the error to whatever code follows the loop.

Another option is to throw an exception.

Really, you should do almost anything other than what you're doing. Currently, when you read one of these 'unreadable' states, you simply `continue` the loop. But `imin` and `imax` still have the same values, so you end up reading the same string from the same place in the vector, and find that it's unreadable again, and so on. You need to decide how you want to respond to one of these 'unreadable' states. I guessed above that you'd want to stop the search, in which case either setting a flag and breaking out of the loop or throwing an exception to accomplish the same thing would be reasonable choices.

Comment: Jan asking for binary search in sequence having "holes". But not for search that stops on random hole.

Comment: @c-smile Without some indication of what the OP expects to happen when such a hole is reached, one can only assume that the search should stop. If there's something else that should happen, then *that* code should go in the body of the condition that tests for unreadability. As is, the OP's code calls `continue` without updating anything, so it's no surprise that the code hangs in that case.

Comment: Consider sorted vector with words, some of them are, say, non-polite. You need to find "closest" polite word.

Comment: @c-smile That makes sense, but I see nothing in the OP's question to indicate that a closest match is actually the desired behavior, or that simply stopping isn't the desired behavior.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I did not indicate that, but my goal is not to simple stop at a hole but rather continue with another item in a still efficient way.

Comment: @Caleb I'm aware of the endless loop issue, that's why I'm asking for a known approach to this. I didn't want to start with a random approach and then discover that other people already had better approaches.

Comment: @Jan Beyond what I've written, how can we possibly know what *your* code should do? There are all sorts of possible strategies for fining the best/closest match, but *we* don't know what "best" or "closest" mean in the context of your problem. You asked *specifically* about the infinite loop and how to avoid it: the answer, again, is either to stop the loop or to modify the state that controls the loop. **That is as much as anybody can tell you about your problem given the information you've provided.**

Comment: @Caleb I could also just delete the whole loop to avoid it in the first place. I think you could try to use a little bit of common sense, I can't post my whole specification and implementation here. Why are you being so petty about this? Other users seemed to understand what I was asking.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of pointers to your data items. Do not add "unreadable" ones. Search the resulting list of pointers.

Comment: How is it different from lookup through all elements? Typical `O(N)` operation, while binary search is `O(log(N))`.

Comment: A list of pre-filtered pointers avoids the redundancy of hitting the same "unreadable" item again and again. And that list is very amenable to using `qsort` as a prelude to the binary search. I didn't mean to exclude binary search as a technique, but did mean to create a pre-filtered list that could then be used with confidence.

Comment: In order "to create a pre-filtered list" you will need to scan whole list. 
Just put there condition `if(compare(text[i], search) < 0)  break;`  and you are done - item found as sequence is sorted. But as I said that is `O(N)` complex operation.

Comment: I can't spent the extra overhead of filtering unfortunately. I'm using binary search because I need the performance. Otherwise I could just use a linear search in the first place.